# Image Doesnt Appear In The Hovering Navigation Bar

Tags: html, css, blogger

The issue I'm having is with an image that I would like to have appear alongside the search bar default wording "search". Even though I have coded in the URL for the image I would like to appear, the image doesn't appear.  I have installed a custom search bar by following the instructions in this tutorial - http://www.bloominrouge.com/2015/01/a-simple-and-sleek-search-bar-widget.html.

Below I have included the entire coding for the search bar:

```
<style>

  #search {    
    background: url (https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-pVUC_2t4N3Q/VHUyuRgha5I/AAAAAAAAC6g/Wm6jR3X_21U/h120/search3.png) 98% 50% no-repeat;
    text-align: left; 
    margin-right:-4%;
    width: 100%;  
    float:right;
    max-width: 210px;
    border: 0;
  }  
  #searchform {
    height: 20px;
}
 #search #s {  
    background: #f8f8f8;  
    color: #333333; 
    font-size: 10px!important; 
    font-family: karla, arial;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: normal;
    letter-spacing: 0.09em;
    border: 0;  
    width: 60%;
    padding: 0;  
    margin: 0;  
    outline: none;  
    position: relative;
    top: 9px;
    padding-left: 6px;
  }  

</style>

<div id='search' title='Type and hit enter'> 
  <form action='/search' id='searchform' method='get'> 
    <input id='s' name='q' onblur='if (this.value == &quot;&quot;) {this.value = &quot;Search&quot;;}' onfocus='if (this.value == &quot;Search&quot;) {this.value = &quot;&quot;;}' type='text' value='Search'/> 
  </form> 
</div>  
<br/><br/>
```

I have tried on multiple occasions to adjust the margin and padding numberings to see if the high number of margin and padding elements aren't interfering with the image but to no avail. I have also tried inserting different images but even that hasn't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
#search {    
    background: url(https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-pVUC_2t4N3Q/VHUyuRgha5I/AAAAAAAAC6g/Wm6jR3X_21U/h120/search3.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:98% 5px;
    text-align: left; 
    width: 100%;  
    float:right;
    max-width: 210px;
    border: 0;
  }  

 #search #s {  
    background: #f8f8f8;  
    color: #333333; 
    font-size: 10px!important; 
    font-family: karla, arial;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: normal;
    letter-spacing: 0.09em;
    border: 0;  
    width: 60%;
    padding: 0;  
    margin: 0;  
    outline: none;  
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    padding-top:9px;
    padding-left: 6px;
  }
```

The space between url and ( needed deleting and `top:9px` needed changing as it hid anything which overflowed.

Comment: David has answered the question correctly. As long as there is a space there - it is an invalid attribute. Unfortunately even with that fix, it appears that the icon is floating a bit far from the searchbox itself. While it isn't my place, I would recommend placing it inside the input element itself? - see [this JSBin link](https://jsbin.com/xodebelaja/edit?html,css,output) for how it would look.